Azure pipeline fails to store cypress screenshots and videos - ##[error]Path does not exist: D:\a\1\s\cypress\screenshots
Hi I am trying to run cypress tests on azure pipelines and tests run fine but I am having trouble with screen shots and videos.
I get the error ---- ##[error]Path does not exist: D:\a\1\s\cypress\screenshots.
I am not sure if I have missed a step or yml tasks have mistakes.  
I tried using "CypressTests/cypress/screenshots" as well but does not work.
I have attached the screenshots file structure, .yml code and config.js




Figured out what the issue was. Screenshots folder was not found because it was never created during build. The reason for that was because in package.json the script was '"cypress:run": "cypress run".
I replaced it with "cypress:run": "npx cypress run", and it works just fine.
The replaced script let cypress create screenshots folder by default.
Here is the snippet from package.json
"scripts": {
"cypress:open": "cypress open",
"cypress:run": "npx cypress run", ---> This creates screenshot file by default
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},

Also cypress only creates screenshots folder if there is a failed run. So we can add this block to handle it
after(() => {
        // Empty screenshot to ensure the directory is created
        cy.screenshot('final-screenshot');
      });

